# All steps active in smartwizard 4

Tags: php, jquery, smart-wizard

I've included smartwizard in the forms in my application, and it works great, during insert.
However, during update, I want to show all steps visited, so that instead of clicking on the next button, the user can get directly to the tab s/he wants. 
How can I achieve that?
I understand I may have to make changes in the *_setEvents* function in the main js file, i.e., jquery.smartWizard.min.js, but I can't seem to figure it out..

Comment: Just to know, since I have the same needs, why didn't you made it with SmartTab instead (also from TechLaboratory)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the answer in anchorSettings.
You add the anchorSettings parameter and change the values as follows,

```
anchorClickable         :   true, // Enable/Disable anchor navigation
        enableAllAnchors        :   true, // Activates all anchors clickable all times
        markDoneStep            :   true, // add done css
        enableAnchorOnDoneStep  :   true // Enable/Disable the done steps navigation
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting enableAllSteps to true:

```
$('#wizard').smartWizard({enableAllSteps: true});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $('#smartwizard').smartWizard({
        selected: 0,
        theme: 'default',
        transitionEffect: 'fade',
        showStepURLhash: false,
        anchorSettings: {
            anchorClickable: true, // Enable/Disable anchor navigation
            enableAllAnchors: true, // Activates all anchors clickable all times
            markDoneStep: true, // add done css
            enableAnchorOnDoneStep: true // Enable/Disable the done steps navigation
        },
        lang: { next: 'Next', previous: 'Previous' }
    });
```